# Javascript-Returning a value from a prompt

Tags: javascript, function, procedure, prompt

For instance, if we have:

```
var greeting = "What is your name?";
var userName = prompt(greeting);
```

How would I take the string input from the user to pass along into a procedure? Just as a for instance, we will assume we're telling a story through the console. How would I take that STRING data from the user and pass it along into a function immediately following that?

Yes, I know it's remedial, but I am trying to get a grasp on core concepts.

Comment: `userName` is the return value from prompt().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var greeting = "What is your name?"; 

function getUserName() {
    return prompt(greeting);
}

function yourFunction() {
     alert("Hello "+getUserName());
}

yourFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to use the prompt value:

```
var greeting = "What is your name?";
var userName = prompt(greeting);
if(testUserName(userName))
{
   alert('name is abc');
}
else
{
   alert('name isnt abc');
}

function testUserName(userName)
{
   return userName == 'abc';
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gH4Tt/)

Answer (score 0):

The userName variable is defined at run time as the return value of the prompt and can be passed as a function parameter to be used when the JavaScript is parsed. This is true of almost all returned values and its not just limited to strings.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bradlilley/nGLTf/

```
var userName = prompt("What is your name?");

function foo(bar) {
    if (bar && bar.length) {
        console.log(bar);
        return;
    }
    console.log('The prompt was left empty.');
    return false;    
};

foo(userName);
```